# Html Parser in Windows 8

Tags: html-parsing, windows-8, windows-runtime

Is there an Html parser for windows 8? I tried to look into the api reference, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not.  Somebody will have to port the agility pack to winrt

Answer (score 5):

I ported HtmlAgilityPack to Metro.

https://bitbucket.org/antiufo/htmlagilitypack-for-metro/

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean Metro apps. Try the Windows.Data.Html namespace in WinRT.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.html.aspx

S

Comment: yea, I mean Metro apps. But the HtmlUtilities is not what I want. I want to extract content from specific tag with specific classes or ids using XPATH. Just like "Html Agility Pack".